# "Apex action method must be static and annotated with AuraEnabled" but it is already static and annotated

Tags: apex, soql, lightning-web-components

```
public with sharing class Data {
    public static List<Object> getObjects() {
        @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
        //code
        return list;
        
    }
}
```

I'm working on an Apex class that uses SOQL to load data from my salesforce org. When I try to deploy, it gives me the error
`Apex action method must be static and annotated with AuraEnabled.`
But I already make it static and also have AuraEnabled annotation. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The annotation needs to appear BEFORE the method declaration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
public static List<Loan_Application__c> getLoanApplications() {
        @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
```

to:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Loan_Application__c> getLoanApplications() {
```

Comment: Wow. I don't know how I missed that, thank you so much. Was staring at this for an hour